# TrueZIP for retrieving remote APK descriptors

Tags: java, android, truezip

According to the TrueZIP documentation, the `TPath` class can retrieve an entry from within an online archive file (https://truezip.java.net/truezip-path/index.html).

I wrote a simple program to try and simulate that:

```
String path = "http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download?file=smartgit/smartgit-win32-setup-jre-7_1_3.zip/changelog.txt";
TPath tpath = new TPath(new URI(path));
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(tpath)) {
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(in));
}
```

That prints the html content of the page I would've seen had I entered the URL denoted by the `path` variable using my browser, instead of the expected contents of `changelog.txt`.

However, my goal is retrieving the contents of an APK's AndroidManifest.xml file remotely without having to download the whole APK.
To my understanding and according to their documentation, TrueZIP should be able to do that. What am I missing?